# Sequantially run two javascript functions using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, setinterval

Here is my code:-

```
function myFunction1()
{
current && aus[current].animate({fill: "#fff", stroke: "#999"}, 200) && (document.getElementById(current).style.display = "");
st.animate({fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#000"}, 200);
R.safari();
document.getElementById(state).style.display = "block";
current = state;
}

function myFunction2()
{
st.animate({fill: "#fff", stroke: "#999"}, 200);
R.safari();
document.getElementById(state).style.display = "";
}

setInterval(function() {
myFunction1();
alert("MOVE"); 
myFunction2();
}, 2000);
```

The thing i am doing were is executing two functions step by step with respect to time... So, i used setInterval event for it, `myFunction1()` is a function to show color and stroke appearance of a path of a **raphaeljs** code and `myFunction2()` is a function to hide color and stroke appearance of a path...

But when calling these function like that does work any how... On alert between the functions may show the result but not like that as i wanted, how to fix this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var intervalFunctions = [ myFunction1, myFunction2 ];
var intIndex = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
  intervalFunctions[intIndex++ % intervalFunctions.length]();
}, 2000);
```

**OR**

```
function1() {

      ....

  function2() //<<========== call here once function1() is executed 
}

function2() {

     ....
}
```

**Image** Victoria and Tasmania
*Victoria*

[image]

**Tasmania**

[image]

Comment: That's fine if you want 2 seconds before and after the first call.  It's not truly sequential.

Comment: Neither your posts do what the OP is asking.  Ahmad has a much better solution, taking my comment about the callback into account.

Comment: @Archer oh so you down voted lol? really I think this post is fine and not worth down voting anyways! cheers!

Comment: It does not answer the question.  How does that not deserve a downvote?  Surely there is no better reason for a downvote.

Comment: @Archer ha ha okies, cool man, not arguing buddy! chill out! You can provide solution if you want man `:)` also see my second reply i.e. **or** option,

Comment: @Tats_innit your first code works but non item displays expect the last one,it fadein and fadeout sequeantially, i have alerted in between `setInterval`, i think your code needs modification...

Comment: @SaurabhLP thank-you for at least mentioning that this will work `:)` anyhoo if you can flick me jsfiddle then it will be awesome I can help you out, although I will be bailing off to sleep soon, so sooner will be better, `:)`

Comment: @SaurabhLP bingo, correct, good use of the functionality, I reckon this is happening because the loop for the lattitude / longitude if not present? hence `function1` and `2` don't know much about it. `:)`

Comment: @SaurabhLP funny enough your fiddle is showing me 2 blinking areas like this: http://jsfiddle.net/29NRH/1/ see 2 images above. `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit thanx for the assistance but your code is working any how i don't know how but its working now...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13337/discussion-between-tats-innit-and-saurabhlp)

Comment: @SaurabhLP no worries at all, glad it worked :) have a good one!

Answer (score 2):

in your case ,The **animate** functions run in **parallel**.

to let them run Sequentially you must run the f2 in the callback of the f1

try to rewrite your code in the below structure
example :

```
 st.animate({fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#000"}, 200,function(){
  myFunction2();
});
```

Comment: Or see post below for sequential function execution `:)` I reckon s/he is aiming for function1() then function2() to execute. B-)